# How do I break the lock chain in Bioshock 2?

Tags: bioshock-2

My search for Adam has brought me in front of a door that is locked by a lock chain. As drilling, electrocuting and incinerator did not suffice to mend it, I wonder:

If I want to break it as soon as possible, what skill do I have to get?

[image: Screenshot of Bioshock 2 standing in front of the lock.]

Comment: What level is this on?  If I am remembering correctly, I think that opens automatically after completing more of the story.

Comment: @Batophobia It is rather at the beginning. If it is story-related, I guess I find out soon.

Comment: Have you tried shooting/kicking it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the [King Pawn](http://bioshock.wikia.com/wiki/King_Pawn) shop, located in [Pauper's Drop](http://bioshock.wikia.com/wiki/Pauper's_Drop_(Level))
[image: King Pawn]

Getting in is story related. You need to

> progress in the story until it asks you to find the camera. Once you get the message, come back here, and a brute will break it open for you